# Dart: simpler way to find and adjust an Map inside the List

Tags: flutter, dart

I have user list and map like below

```
user = [
   {'user': 'John', 'id': 'aaa'},
   {'user': 'Jane', 'id': 'aa1'},
];
```

I want to find `Jane` and change her id as 'aa3'. Currently, I am searching the `index` inside the `user[]`. And then use that index to update the value of `id`.

```
   int i =  user.indexWhere((e) => e.name == 'Jane');
   user[i]['id'] = 'aa1';
```

Is there any way that I can do this at once? It seems very inefficient way to do it, but couldn't find the better way yet.

Comment: It's inefficient because you picked an inefficient data structure.  If usernames are unique, then it'd be more straightforward to use a `Map<String, User>` that maps usernames to `User` objects.

Comment: I am quite confused. Are you suggesting to add the generic to the list?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that you replace your `List<Map<...>>` with a `Map<String, User>`.

Comment: Ohhhh, I get it now. Like `{'Jane': User-Attr-of-Jane, 'John': ---}`. Because of the name is not redundant, I can use the `Map` and I don't need to find the index to adjust it. Interesting. I was getting the data as a List. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all really depends on how "performant" you need the solution to be. If I were you, I would first look at parsing that data into its own `Person` class. Let's have a look at an example:

```dart
@immutable
class Person {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  const Person({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant Person other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

Here I've overridden the `==` operator so that two `Person` instances that have the same `id` are considered to be equal. After you override this operator, you're recommended to override the `hashCode` getter as well and that is used for finding instances of your object inside a `Map<T, E>`.

Then I would place these `Person` instances inside a `Map<String, Person>` where the `String` keys inside the map would be IDs of the `Person` instances like so:

```dart
final persons = const {
  'aaa': Person(id: 'aaa', name: 'John'),
  'aa1': Person(id: 'aa1', name: 'Jane'),
};
```

After doing that, you can easily find your objects like this:

```dart
final aaa = persons['aaa'];
final aa1 = persons['aa1'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Travers through the list of users, simultaneously check for the respective
user, when you will find one change its id and break from the loop.

try this :

```dart
  for(int i =0;i<user.length;i++)
  {
    var single_user=user[i];
    if(single_user['user']=='Jane'){
      single_user['id']="aa3";
      //or any changes as you want
      break;
    }
  }
```